# change basic DOM to jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

So I would like to change the container variable in the following code to be a JQuery object. The method I am using is not working.... The container doesn't load. The init() function is not called.

EDIT: I've trimmed down the code in the .js file.

letterpaint.js:

```
(function(){

  /* Get container elements */

  //var container = document.querySelector('#container'); 
  var charscontainer = document.querySelector('#chars');


  var container = $('#container'); //************//
  //var charscontainer = $("#chars");

  /* Prepare canvas */
  var c = document.querySelector('canvas');
  //var c = $('canvas')[0];
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var letter = null;
  var fontsize = 300;
  var paintcolour = [240, 240, 240];
  var textcolour = [255, 30, 20];
  var xoffset = 0;
  var yoffset = 0;
  var linewidth = 20;
  var pixels = 0;
  var letterpixels = 0;

  /* Overall game presets */
  var state = 'intro';
  var currentstate;



  function init() {
    var temp = container.offset();
    xoffset = temp.left;
    yoffset = temp.top;
    fontsize = container.offsetHeight / 1.5;
    linewidth = container.offsetHeight / 19;

    /*
    xoffset = container.offsetLeft;
    yoffset = container.offsetTop;
    fontsize = container.offsetHeight / 1.5;
    linewidth = container.offsetHeight / 19;
    */
    paintletter();
    setstate('intro');
  }

  function setstate(newstate) {
    state = newstate;
    container.removeClass('container').addClass(newState.toString());
    //container.className = newstate;
    currentsate = state;
  }
  function moreneeded() {
    setstate('play');
    mousedown = false;
  }
  function retry(ev) {
    mousedown = false;
    oldx = 0;
    oldy = 0;
    paintletter(letter);
    //start the timer
    timer = 10;
    startTimer = true;
  }
  function winner() {
    score +=1;
    //reset timer
    timer = 10;
    //start timer again
    startTimer = true;
    //$("#score").html(score.toString());
    document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = score.toString();
    paintletter();
  }
  function start() {
    paintletter(letter);
    startTimer = true;
  }
  function cancel() {
    //reset timer
    timer = 10;
    paintletter();
  }
  function paintletter(retryletter) {
    var chars = charscontainer.innerHTML.split('');
    letter = retryletter ||
             chars[parseInt(Math.random() * chars.length,10)];
    c.width = container.offsetWidth;
    c.height = container.offsetHeight;
    cx.font = 'bold ' + fontsize + 'px Open Sans';
    cx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + textcolour.join(',') + ')';
    cx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(' + paintcolour.join(',') + ')';
    cx.shadowOffsetX = 2;
    cx.shadowOffsetY = 2;
    cx.shadowBlur = 4;
    cx.shadowColor = '#666';

    cx.textBaseline = 'baseline';
    cx.lineWidth = linewidth;
    cx.lineCap = 'round';
    cx.fillText(
      letter,
      (c.width - cx.measureText(letter).width) / 2,
      (c.height / 1.3)
    );
    pixels = cx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    letterpixels = getpixelamount(
      textcolour[0],
      textcolour[1],
      textcolour[2]
    );
    cx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
    cx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
    cx.shadowBlur = 0;
    cx.shadowColor = '#333';
    setstate('play');
  }

  function getpixelamount(r, g, b) {
    var pixels = cx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    var all = pixels.data.length;
    var amount = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < all; i += 4) {
      if (pixels.data[i] === r &&
          pixels.data[i+1] === g &&
          pixels.data[i+2] === b) {
        amount++;
      }
    }
    return amount;
  }

  function paint(x, y) {
    var rx = x - xoffset;
    var ry = y - yoffset;
    var colour = pixelcolour(x, y);
    if( colour.r === 0 && colour.g === 0 && colour.b === 0) {
      showerror();
      //stop timer
      startTimer = false;
    } else {
      cx.beginPath();
      if (oldx > 0 && oldy > 0) {
        cx.moveTo(oldx, oldy);
      }
      cx.lineTo(rx, ry);
      cx.stroke();
      cx.closePath();
      oldx = rx;
      oldy = ry;
    }
  }

  function pixelcolour(x, y) {
    var index = ((y * (pixels.width * 4)) + (x * 4));
    return {
      r:pixels.data[index],
      g:pixels.data[index + 1],
      b:pixels.data[index + 2],
      a:pixels.data[index + 3]
    };
  }

  function pixelthreshold() {
    if (state !== 'error') {
      if (getpixelamount(
        paintcolour[0],
        paintcolour[1],
        paintcolour[2]
      ) / letterpixels > 0.35) {
       setstate('win');
       if (sound) {
         winsound.play();
         //stop the timer
         startTimer = false;
       }
      }
    }
  }

  /* Mouse event listeners */

  function onmouseup(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    oldx = 0;
    oldy = 0;
    mousedown = false;
    pixelthreshold();
  }
  function onmousedown(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    mousedown = true;
  }
  function onmousemove(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    if (mousedown) {
      paint(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener('load',init, false);
  window.addEventListener('resize',init, false);

  //added for timer count every second
  window.setInterval(function(){timerCount()}, 1000);

})();
```

letterpaint.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>letterpaint</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="letterpaint.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="container">

    <div id="chars" class="gamedata">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789</div>

    <canvas></canvas>

    <h1 class="toppanel">letterpaint</h1>

    <div id="intro" class="cover">
      <p>Paint over the letter you see on the screen. Can you write it without going outside of it?</p>
      <button class="actionbutton">➜</button>
    </div>

    <button id="sound" class="navbutton">♬</button>
    <button id="infos" class="navbutton">i</button>
    <button id="quit" class="navbutton">q</button>

    <div id="win" class="cover check">
      <p>Good job!</p> 
      <button class="actionbutton">➜</button>
    </div>

    <div id="error" class="cover">
      <p>You painted outside the letter!</p> 
      <button class="actionbutton">➜</button>
    </div>

    <div id="info" class="cover infopanel">
      <h1>letterpaint</h1>
      <p>version 1.0-2406-1</p>
      <p>Written by Chris Heilmann</p>
      <p>modified by Anil Somayaji</p>
      <p>Original version <a href="https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/06/building-a-simple-paint-game-with-html5-canvas-and-vanilla-javascript/">here</a> (<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/">CC BY-SA 3.0</a>).
    </div>

    <button class="actionbutton undo" id="reload">X</button>

    <div class="score" id="score">
        0
    </div>

    <div class="timer" id="timer">
        0
    </div>

    <div class="message" id="encourageMessage">

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- http://freesound.org/people/NenadSimic/sounds/150879/ -->
  <audio src="win.ogg" id="winsound"></audio>
  <!-- http://freesound.org/people/Autistic%20Lucario/sounds/142608/ -->
  <audio src="error.ogg" id="errorsound"></audio>

  <script src="letterpaint.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> //unsure if this is needed
</body>
</html>
```

letterpaint.css:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(opensans.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(opensans-bold.ttf) format('truetype');
}

body, html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', times, arial, sans-serif;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
canvas {
  background: #ccc;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #fc6, #ffc);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.gamedata {
  display: none;
}
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 80px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-120%,0);
  transform: translate(-120%,0);
} 

.info #info {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.win #win {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.error #error {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.intro #intro {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.cover p {
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 6vw;
}
.navbutton {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  display: block;
  right: 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #060;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.navbuttonoff {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  display: block;
  right: 5px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.actionbutton {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  display: block;
  right: 20px;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #060;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50% 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.inlinebutton {
  float: right;
  background: #060;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 3vw;
}
#infos {
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 55px;
}

#quit {
  font-weight: bold;
  right: 105px;
}
.score {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 100px;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.timer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  right: 100px;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.message {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.actionbutton.undo {
  background: #900;
  color: #fff;
  left: -100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #333;
}
.play .undo {
  left: 10px;
}

.check p::after {
  content: '✔';
  font-size: 20vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 60%;
  color: #060;
  color: rgba(0,200,0,0.4);
}

.toppanel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background: #000;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #000, #333);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.infopanel h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.infopanel p {
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 10px;
}  
@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
  .infopanel h1 {
    font-size: 8vw;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }
  .infopanel p {
    font-size: 5vw;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
  }  
}
```

I am unsure why my code for var containter = $('#container') is not working. I've also tried '.container' but can't get that to work either.

I've tried to just change a button (like startbutton) to JQuery as well but have had the same problem. The init function (window eventhandler) is not being called...Why?

There are no console errors.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Any errors in the console? As it stands now this is way to much code to look through, narrow it down to only the relevant pieces.

Comment: You have to load the jQuery library ***BEFORE*** you load your script file.

Comment: It's basically the answer.

Comment: Like @adeneo said, the problem most likely lies in the fact that your libraries are being called after your functions. Move your 2 `script` tags to within the header and see if that works.

Comment: ^^^ that would also require a DOM ready function, just moving the jQuery script tag up a few places will solve this.

Comment: Thank you! I did this but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `letterpaint.js` script is called and executed before `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`, so the jQuery functionality in your custom script isn't working because jQuery is not loaded yet.

Just move `<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` above `<script src="letterpaint.js"></script>` in the markup.

It might be a good idea to load jQuery in the `head`, and load other scripts at the end of the `body` like you do now (this is what I do on most sites that I build that are heavily dependent on jQuery).  You can also move both scripts to be in the `head` but you'd need to wrap the code in `letterpaint.js` in a `$(document).ready()` function like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // your custom letterpaint.js code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped. But the init() function is still not running.